# OS X Partition debacle

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, osx-mavericks, osx-el-capitan

Here's what I did.

I was on OS X Mavericks on my 1Tb SSD internal drive.

I wanted to do a clean install of OS X El Capitan so I made a 80Gb partition for it and installed it on the new partition. All good.

Once all was running smooth I wanted to resize the Mavericks 920Gb partition to something like 100Gb and assign the remaining space to the El Capitan partition and bring that from 80 to 900Gb.

In Disk Utility on El Capitan it wouldn't let me do that. The only thing it would let me do is create a third partition in the unused space, so I did that thinking it was an in between step.

Once I created that it wouldn't let me merge that with the El Capitan partition so I tried booting the system on the old OS X Mavericks and try Disk Utilities there. I removed the new (third) empty partition hoping it would then let me assign that space to the El Capitan partition but no dice.

Now I am stuck in this limbo where I cannot resize either of the partitions AND the previously empty space has vanished. I now see a 350Gb Mavericks partition and an 80Gb El Capitan partition and the other 570Gb of space are nowhere to be seen.

How do I get out of this situation and how can I resize these partitions?

I did try to start from a recovery disk and try Disk Utilities there but same thing. I need help.

Thanks a lot for your suggetsions.

Comment: As a general recommendation: make sure you have backups of anything important before messing with it any more!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that behavior on one of my iMac's. I'd recommend trying to use Terminal in your Recovery Partition and using the

```
diskutil resizeVolume
```

command you can try to reallocate the space to one of the partitions. You can read more on it at [MacWorld](http://www.macworld.com/article/1055274/software-utilities/marchgeekfactor.html) where they did a write-up on it pretty extensibly. Of course it's not a guarantee that it will work but it's worth a shot. Just make sure you have a backup of the data because otherwise you'll have to format the drive and size the partitions how you want then reinstall OS X.